# Yelp API calls using Jersey REST Client

Tags: java, jersey-client, yelp

I am trying to make REST calls to the `Yelp API` to get business data from my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. I am able to make the API call using `Postman App`. Now I am trying to use the Jersey REST client. My `REST` call will be as follows:

```java
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/{id}");
Object responseMsg = webResource
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer My_Key")
    .getClass();
```

According the Yelp documentation [Yelp Documentation](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/get_started), an object will be returned if I make the API call. Is it not possible to store the returned data into a `Java Oject` and get the required data from that Object.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even making a request. You need to use one of the methods on the [`WebResource.Builder`](http://javadox.com/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.18/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.Builder.html). Once you call `header()` on the `WebResource`, you get back a `WebResource.Builder`. To make the API call, you need to use a method like `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, etc. Pass `ClientResponse.class` as the argument so you get back a `ClientResponse`. The you can check the status on the `ClientResponse`. If the status is ok, then call `response.getEntity(POJO.class)`, where `POJO.class` is your own model class representation of the Yelp JSON data. Something like

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer My_Key")
        .get(ClientResponse.class);
if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
    YelpModel model = response.getEntity(YelpModel.class);
}
```

You need to make sure you have the `jersey-json` dependency and configure the JSON POJO feature with the client

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();              
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE); 
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

`YelpModel` is your custom POJO class that models the Yelp JSON. If you don't know how to make this class, then you might need to go over some Jackson tutorials on how to map JSON to Java objects.